# Debug and Release package with productFlavors

Tags: android, build.gradle, dagger, android-build-flavors

I have created 2 `productFlavors` in `build.gradle` file

```
productFlavors {
        flavorA {
            dimension "default"
        }

        flavorB {
            dimension "default"
        }
    }
```

And 2 `buildTypes` `debug` and `release`

So gradle created `Build Variants` as  `flavorADebug`, `flavorARelease`, `flavorBDebug` and `flavorBRelease`

I want to create a `FlavorDI` file in `debug` and `release` package such that `debug/FlavorDI` will be common for `flavorADebug` and `flavorBDebug` and `release/FlavorDI` will be common for `flavorARelease` and `flavorBRelease`.

But when I include the `FlavorDI` in `AppComponent` the package is not recognized.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AppModule::class,
    ActivityModule::class,
    FragmentModule::class,
    ViewModelModule::class,
    NetModule::class,
    FlavourDI::class,   // Could not import FlavourDI
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    AndroidInjectionModule::class
])
```

How exactly should I create the `FlavorDI` file such that `debug/FlavorDI` will be common to `flavorADebug` and `flavorBDebug` variant and `release/FlavorDI` will be common to `flavorARelease` and `flavorBRelease` variant?

[image]

Comment: what exactly do you need on the class you're injecting? it is better to put an if else statement to check the flavor and use the corresponding code instead of dividing them in package (in this case, dividing it via package flavor doesn't work)

Comment: You're doing it wrong. in spite of debug and release directory, make your **flavorA** and **flavorB** directories, then put your flavor specific code there

Comment: @JeelVankhede then I have to create a seperate package for each build variant. I don't want that. I simply want two packages i.e. debug and release for each for the productFlavors

Comment: I don't think multi flavor build works that way.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the proper build variant. Also, you might need to use `flavorDimension`. This is what I have for a similar setup in my `build.gradle`:

```
flavorDimensions 'mobile'

productFlavors {
    internal {
        dimension = 'mobile'
        applicationId = 'com.labs.biletskiy.android.internal'
    }

    production {
        dimension = 'mobile'
        applicationId 'com.labs.biletskiy.android.production'
    }

}
```

Comment: I have build variants as flavorADebug, flavorARelease, flavorBDebug, and flavorBRelease. And FlavorDI class is in debug and release package. Which build variant should I select? It is not working with any of the build variants.

Comment: And yes, I have included flavorDimensions as well

Comment: Also, make sure the package declaration is correct in that missing file.